# Python Pandas Series - order output via Slice

Tags: python, pandas, series

Trying to produce an 'ordered' output from a Pandas Series using the Slice notation. The example below seems to be in err.

```
x = pd.Series([2,4,6], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(x[2,1])   #Fail
```

Comment: Try this: `x[[1,2]]`

Comment: You've gotta enclose that in a list.

Comment: you're using a series, so `x[2,1]` cannot work since a series is 1d. In the other cases i would suggest you to use `.iloc[...]` or `.loc[...]` and keep the example of MaxU in mind

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little bit on the comments, pandas uses the `[...]` to figure out the row, column coordinates it's looking up. So if you wanted to pick out 2 items: the item at row 2 and the item at row 1, you need to tell pandas that it's looking for a list of rows. Hence:

```
# x[rows, columns]
x[[2,1]]
```

will return what you want.